# Check If input number within the range using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Check if input within the range in array. Suppose, if input value is 12 the answer should be ball.

```
var ranges = [{"1-10":"Apple"},{"11-20":"Ball"},{"21-30":"Cat"}]
var input_number = 12;
var get_answer = ...  // should be "Ball"
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of objects with different keys, instead of a single object like `{"1-10": "Apple", "11-20": "Ball", "21-30": "Cat"}`?

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks for your response. If I use in single object then How can I find my input number in given ranges.

Comment: Loop over all the properties of the object, split the key into a start and end number, compare the input number with with them, and return the value if it's in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple code for you

```js
var ranges = [{"1-10":"Apple"},{"11-20":"Ball"},{"21-30":"Cat"}]

function getAns(input_number) {
  let result = null
  // handle input ranges
  for (let index in ranges) {
    for (let key in ranges[index]) {
      let min = key.split('-')[0]
      let max = key.split('-')[1]
      if (input_number >= min && input_number <= max) {
        result = ranges[index][key]
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(getAns(12))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a filter

```js
const getValue = (value, ranges) => {
  const res = ranges.filter(obj => {
    const [min, max] = Object.keys(obj)[0].split("-");
    return value >= +min && value <= +max;
  })
  return res && res.length > 0 ?  Object.values(res[0])[0] :  "N/A"
}

const ranges = [{"1-10":"Apple"},{"11-20":"Ball"},{"21-30":"Cat"}]

console.log(getValue(0,ranges))
console.log(getValue(1,ranges))
console.log(getValue(12,ranges))
console.log(getValue(30,ranges))
console.log(getValue(31,ranges))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ranges.map(x=> Object.entries(x).flat() )
      .find(a=> (a[0]=a[0].split`-`, n>=a[0][0] && n<=a[0][1] && a[1]) )
```

```js
var ranges = [{"1-10":"Apple"},{"11-20":"Ball"},{"21-30":"Cat"}]
var n=12;

var r = ranges.map( x=>Object.entries(x).flat() )
              .find(a=> (a[0]=a[0].split`-`, n>=a[0][0] && n<=a[0][1] && a[1]) )
console.log(r[1]);
```

Comment: So hard to read. Why not use some descriptive var names? Beginners will not get much out of this answer